# Excel Formula using IF and SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a working SUMIFS formula.

```
=SUMIFS(Test1!D:D,Test1!B:B,A5,Test1!A:A,B$3,Test1!E:E,$A$2)
```

This returns a value of 0.05 (minutes)

How do I add an IF statement to that same formula? To calculate anything equal to or greater than five minutes will equal a value of 10, and if less than five minutes, will equal a value of zero?

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | 0.03 |
| User2 | 0.05 |

To become

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | 0 |
| User2 | 10 |

Comment: `=IF(CONDITION=TRUE,RESULT1,RESULT2)` As simple as that. Replace the CONDITION with `SUMIFS(Test1!D:D,Test1!B:B,A5,Test1!A:A,B$3,Test1!E:E,$A$2)>=.05` and `RESULT1` with `10` and `RESULT2` with `0`.